# Created a nested ArrayList from a string

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, arraylist

I am looking to created an ArrayList that is the exact replica of a String representation of a nested list.
So given "[4, 9, 12, [1,2,3], [5,6,10], [11,12]]" the list would be [4,9,12,[1,2,3],[5,6,10],[11,12]].

```
static int position =0;

public static ArrayList stringToList(String input) {
       List<ArrayList> parsedList = new ArrayList<>();

        while(position < input.length()){
            char element = input.charAt(position++);


            if(element == '['){
                parsedList.add(parseListsToString(input));
            }else if(element==']'){
                break;
            }else if(element==','){}
            else{
                parsedList.add(element);
            }

        }

        return parsedList;
    }
```

I have tried declaring parsedList as: ArrayList(ArrayList) (which allows for recursion) and ArrayList(Integer) (which doesn't allow for recursion). And in the current code that I submitted about is obviously wrong because parsedList is an incorrect return type because its not an ArrayList.

I believe that my method in going about the problem is right just that my understanding of ArrayList is lacking and that is where I need help. So any suggestions would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this even possible? What type of `ArrayList` can hold a both an `Integer` and a `List`?

Comment: something like ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>. It is very possible.

Comment: you are missing ] after the first '12'. In your testing String

Comment: I have tried the ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> method and I am unable to add the elements to it because they are not of type ArrayList. And there shouldn't be a ']' after the first 12 as it is part of the outer most array. [4,9,12, [nested], [nested], [nested]], unless you think that's wrong. Do I need to manipulate the element in someway to add it if I define it as ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>?

Comment: I will edit my answer

Comment: Ok, so this is not possible because an `ArrayList`, or any other `List` in Java, can only "contain" one type. So let's say you want a list of integers: it would look something like this: `List<Integer>`. What you want is something like this: `List<Integer OR List<Integer>>`, which is not possible!

Comment: If you have a integer just add it to a an arraylist that will contain only that integer. It is possible to work around it. And the result would be someting like [[4],[9],[12],[1,2,3],[5,6,10],[11,12]]

Comment: If any of the answer have helped you please accept it to point out the correct solution!

Answer (score 1):

Hi I debbuged and tested this solution.

```
String input = "[4, 9, 12, [1,2,3], 2, [5,6,10], [11,12],2,4 ,[5,6]]"; 
List<ArrayList<Integer>> parsedList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();      
    int count = -1;
    boolean newArray = true;

    String element = "";
    for(int i = 1; i < input.length()-1; i++){

        char temp = input.charAt(i); 
        element += temp;

        if(temp == '['){
            parsedList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
            count++;
            element = "";
            newArray = false;
        }
        else if(temp == ']'){ 
            parsedList.get(count).add(Integer.parseInt(element.replaceAll("]","")));                    element ="";                
            newArray = true;

        }
        else if(temp == ',' && element.length() == 1 ){

             element = "";  

        }
        else if(temp == ',' && element.length() != 1){

            if(newArray){
                parsedList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
                count++;                    
            }

            parsedList.get(count).add(Integer.parseInt(element.replaceAll(",","").replaceAll(" ", "")));
            element ="";

        }

    }
```

The result is [[4],[9],[12],[1,2,3],[2],[5,6,10],[11,12],[2],[4],[5,6]].
So basically yo have an array of integer arrays.

Comment: It will not work for multi-dimensional arrays... Also, why do you have every number in a single List?

Comment: Well it answers the question.

Comment: Well, yes. @bigkat79 has posted this question again this day. With the same name. The question there was a bit different, but really a bit.

But he has deleted it...

Answer (score 0):

I posted my solution previously, but it disappeared:

```
private static List<Object> toArray(final String str) {
    return Main.toArray(new StringBuilder(str));
}

private static List<Object> toArray(final StringBuilder data) {
    final List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();

    if (data.charAt(0) == '[') {
        data.delete(0, 1);
    }

    String value = "";
    while (data.length() > 0) {
        final char element = data.charAt(0);
        data.delete(0, 1);

        if (element == '[') {
            result.add(Main.toArray(data));
        } else if (element == ']') {
            if (!value.isEmpty()) {
                result.add(value);
                value = "";
            }
            break;
        } else if (element == ',') {
            if (!value.isEmpty()) {
                result.add(value);
                value = "";
            }
        } else if (element != ' ') {
            value += element;
        }
    }

    if (!value.isEmpty()) {
        result.add(value);
    }

    return result;
}
```